# get column name from mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to know how can we get the column name from the table where `data=this` is the condition.

Suppose I want to get the column name where `data="this"` where this is the data present in that column

```
      username

      ram
      sham
      gaurav
```

here `username` is the column name and i want to get this name on the basis of `ram,sham` etc

Comment: Do you mean "for each row in my table, tell me which column has the value 'xxx'" ?

Comment: Provide more complex example of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW COLUMNS` displays information about the columns in a given table. The `LIKE` clause, if present, indicates which column names to match. The `WHERE` clause can be given to select rows using more general conditions.

Here's the syntax :

```
SHOW [FULL] COLUMNS {FROM | IN} tbl_name [{FROM | IN} db_name]
    [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

Comment: can you write the above command for the example i gave in the question

Comment: get username(column name on the basis of ram,sham etc)

Comment: Nice.. but i wonder why MySQL use `COLUMNS` instead `COLOUMNS`, is there have different meaning? (im not native english)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $dataurl=mysql_fetch_field($query,$indexr_numberfields_in_one_row);

 $valueurl=$arrayurl[$dataurl->name];

 $col5=$dataurl->name;
```