# MySQL Set Table/Column as Variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a few tables in a database using MySQL (The engine is MyISAM). I am trying to find the lengths of the longest strings in each column (all of the data is text). Right now I am trying to run code that looks like:

```
SELECT LENGTH(col) FROM schema.table ORDER BY LENGTH(col) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I have been manually typing in the column names and table names. However, continuing this will take forever.

At the very least, is there a way for me to assign a variable and replace the two instances of `col` with that variable so I don't have to type it repeatedly?

It would be even better if I could, for a given table, iterate over all the columns and get back the length of the longest string in each column.

Thanks!

EDIT: Hybridzz, neither of those two links solves my problem; I can't seem to get MySQL to accept a variable assignment.

I also tried these four searches beforehand:
[MySQL: Assign column value to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760060/mysql-assign-column-value-to-variable)

[Setting columns variably in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702612/setting-columns-variably-in-mysql)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642677/how-to-use-database-name-as-a-value

[mysql, iterate through column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950252/mysql-iterate-through-column-names)

Comment: better search first before post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648420/get-all-columns-from-all-mysql-tables

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416392/get-column-name-from-mysql

I got these two when i did a quick search here

Comment: You can get column names from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database. To use them, you need to write dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic SQL that you want is:

```
select max(length(col1)), max(length(col2)), . . .
from table t;
```

You can get the expression for all columns in the table that are `varchar` by querying `information_schema.columns`:

```
select group_concat('max(length(', column_name, '))' separator ', ')
from information_schema.column
where data_type = 'varchar' and table_name = 'table' and table_schema = 'schema';
```

You can then copy the expressions into a `select`.  Or put them into a string and use `prepare`.